# C# ASP.NET trouble uploading contact page to SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2

Let me start of by saying that I am new to ASP and have done my best to learn the script the past couple weeks. I am having trouble setting up an `aspx.cs` page to get the information to post on the server. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have included the code for the backend and the web form below. The web form is one page that needs to collect text fields, RadioButton, dropdownlist, and checkboxlist.

RadioButton - askes question that requires a Yes or No answer 
Checkboxlist - Inset a 1 if selected and a 0 if not selected.

Needs to be able to work with asp.net 2.0, IIS 6, C#, SQL Server 2008 R2.

I replaced all of the actual ID with numbers****

## Back End

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        //sets the connection string from your web config file "ConnString" is the name of your Connection String
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConString"].ConnectionString;
    }

private void ExecuteInsert(string 1, string 2, string 3, string 4, string 5, string 6, string 7, string 8, string 9, string 10, string 11, string 12, string 13, string 14, string 15, string 16, string 17, string 18, string 19, string 20, string 21, string 22, string 23, string 24, string 25, string 26, string 27, string 28, string 29, string 30, string 31, string 32, string 33, string 34, string 35, string 36, string 37, string 38, string 39, string 40, string 41, string 42, string 43, string 44, string 45, string 46, string 47, string 48, string 49, string 50, string 51, string 52, string 53, string 54, string 55, string 56, string 57, string 58, string 59, string 60, string 61, string 62, string 63, string 64, string 65, string 66)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    string sql = "INSERT INTO webContactForm (1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66) VALUES (@1,  @2,  @3,  @4,  @5,  @6,  @7,  @8,  @9,  @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17, @18, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23, @24, @25, @26, @27, @28, @29, @30, @31, @32, @33, @34, @35, @36, @37, @38, @39, @40, @41, @42, @43, @44, @45, @46, @47, @48, @49, @50, @51, @52, @53, @54, @55, @56, @57, @58, @59, @60, @61, @62, @63, @64, @65, @66)";

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[66];
        //param[0] = new SqlParameter("@Contact_id", SqlDbType.Int, 20);
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@1", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@2", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@3", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[3] = new SqlParameter("@4", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[4] = new SqlParameter("@5", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[5] = new SqlParameter("@6", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[6] = new SqlParameter("@7", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[7] = new SqlParameter("@8", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[8] = new SqlParameter("@9", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[9] = new SqlParameter("@10", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[10] = new SqlParameter("@11", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[11] = new SqlParameter("@12", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[12] = new SqlParameter("@13", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[13] = new SqlParameter("@14", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[14] = new SqlParameter("@15", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[15] = new SqlParameter("@16", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[16] = new SqlParameter("@17", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[17] = new SqlParameter("@18", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[18] = new SqlParameter("@19", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[19] = new SqlParameter("@20", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[20] = new SqlParameter("@21", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[21] = new SqlParameter("@22", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[22] = new SqlParameter("@23", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[23] = new SqlParameter("@24", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[24] = new SqlParameter("@25", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[25] = new SqlParameter("@26", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[26] = new SqlParameter("@27", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[27] = new SqlParameter("@28", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[28] = new SqlParameter("@29", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[29] = new SqlParameter("@30", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[30] = new SqlParameter("@31", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[31] = new SqlParameter("@32", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[32] = new SqlParameter("@33", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[33] = new SqlParameter("@34", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[34] = new SqlParameter("@35", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[35] = new SqlParameter("@36", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[36] = new SqlParameter("@37", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[37] = new SqlParameter("@38", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[38] = new SqlParameter("@39", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[39] = new SqlParameter("@40", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[40] = new SqlParameter("@41", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[41] = new SqlParameter("@42", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[42] = new SqlParameter("@43", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[43] = new SqlParameter("@44", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[44] = new SqlParameter("@45", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[45] = new SqlParameter("@46", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[46] = new SqlParameter("@47", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[47] = new SqlParameter("@48", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[48] = new SqlParameter("@49", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[49] = new SqlParameter("@50", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[50] = new SqlParameter("@51", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[51] = new SqlParameter("@52", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[52] = new SqlParameter("@53", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[53] = new SqlParameter("@54", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[54] = new SqlParameter("@55", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[55] = new SqlParameter("@56", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[56] = new SqlParameter("@57", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[57] = new SqlParameter("@58", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[58] = new SqlParameter("@59", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[59] = new SqlParameter("@60", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[60] = new SqlParameter("@61", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[61] = new SqlParameter("@62", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[62] = new SqlParameter("@63", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[63] = new SqlParameter("@64", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[64] = new SqlParameter("@65", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
        param[65] = new SqlParameter("@66", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);
    param[66] = new SqlParameter("@67", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200);

        param[0].Value = 1;
        param[1].Value = 2;
        param[2].Value = 3;
        param[3].Value = 4;
        param[4].Value = 5;
        param[5].Value = 6;
        param[6].Value = 7;
        param[7].Value = 8;
        param[8].Value = 9;
        param[9].Value = 10;
        param[10].Value = 11;
        param[11].Value = 12;
        param[12].Value = 13;
        param[13].Value = 14;
        param[14].Value = 15;
        param[15].Value = 16;
        param[16].Value = 17;
        param[17].Value = 18;
        param[18].Value = 19;
        param[19].Value = 20;
        param[20].Value = 21;
        param[21].Value = 22;
        param[22].Value = 23;
        param[23].Value = 24;
        param[24].Value = 25;
        param[25].Value = 26;
        param[26].Value = 27;
        param[27].Value = 28;
        param[28].Value = 29;
        param[29].Value = 30;
        param[30].Value = 31;
        param[31].Value = 32;
        param[32].Value = 33;
        param[33].Value = 34;
        param[34].Value = 35;
        param[35].Value = 36;
        param[36].Value = 37;
        param[37].Value = 38;
        param[38].Value = 39;
        param[39].Value = 40;
        param[40].Value = 41;
        param[41].Value = 42;
        param[42].Value = 43;
        param[43].Value = 44;
        param[44].Value = 45;
        param[45].Value = 46;
        param[46].Value = 47;
        param[47].Value = 48;
        param[48].Value = 49;
        param[49].Value = 50;
        param[50].Value = 51;
        param[51].Value = 52;
        param[52].Value = 53;
        param[53].Value = 54;
        param[54].Value = 55;
        param[55].Value = 56;
        param[56].Value = 57;
        param[57].Value = 58;
        param[58].Value = 59;
        param[59].Value = 60;
        param[60].Value = 61;
        param[61].Value = 62;
        param[62].Value = 63;
        param[63].Value = 64;
        param[64].Value = 65;
        param[65].Value = 66;
        param[66].Value = 67;

        //create loop to insert
        for (int i = 0; i < param.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(param[i]);
        }

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Error occured while inserting:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
    }
    private object GetConnectionString(string p)
    {
throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        //call the method to execute insert to the database
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyParamter", "my value"));

        ClearControls(Page);
}
}
```

## WEB FORM CODE:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"" Inherits="Default2" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Contact Us</title>

  </head>
   <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
      <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 1:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 2:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="LName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">3 TextBox column 3,4,5:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="3" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>-
                <asp:TextBox ID="4" runat="server" Width="59px"></asp:TextBox>-
                <asp:TextBox ID="5" runat="server" Width="62px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 6:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="6" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">ListItem column 7:</td>
            <td class="style2">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="7" runat="server"
                              AppendDataBoundItems="true">
            <asp:ListItem Value="-1">Select</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>A</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>B</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>C</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>D</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>E</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>F</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>G</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">RadioButton column 8</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="Yes" runat="server" Checked="True" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="No" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 9:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="9" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 10:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="ClientLName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">RadioButton Column 11:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="Female" runat="server" />
                <asp:RadioButton ID="Male" runat="server" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">3 TextBox column 12,13,14:</td>
            <td class="">
                <asp:TextBox ID="12" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>(mm)/<asp:TextBox ID="13" runat="server" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>(dd)/<asp:TextBox ID="14" runat="server" Width="85px"></asp:TextBox>(yyyy)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 15:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="15" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 16:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="16" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 17:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="17" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">Dropdownlist column 18:</td>
            <td class="style2">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="18" runat="server"
                              AppendDataBoundItems="true">
         <asp:ListItem value="-1">Select State</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="AL">Alabama</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="AR">Arkansas</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="AZ">Arizona</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="CA">California</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="CO">Colorado</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="CT">Connecticut</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="DC">District of Columbia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="DE">Delaware</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="FL">Florida</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="GA">Georgia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="IA">Iowa</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="ID">Idaho</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="IL">Illinois</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="IN">Indiana</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="KS">Kansas</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="KY">Kentucky</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="LA">Louisiana</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MA">Massachusetts</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MD">Maryland</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="ME">Maine</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MI">Michigan</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MN">Minnesota</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MO">Missouri</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MS">Mississippi</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="MT">Montana</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NC">North Carolina</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="ND">North Dakota</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NE">Nebraska</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NH">New Hampshire</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NJ">New Jersey</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NM">New Mexico</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NV">Nevada</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="NY">New York</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="OH">Ohio</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="OK">Oklahoma</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="OR">Oregon</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="PA">Pennsylvania</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="RI">Rhode Island</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="SC">South Carolina</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="SD">South Dakota</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="TN">Tennessee</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="TX">Texas</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="UT">Utah</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="VA">Virginia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="VT">Vermont</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="WA">Washington</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="WI">Wisconsin</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="WV">West Virginia</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem value="WY">Wyoming</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">TextBox column 19:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="19" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
        <h1>
        Providing:
       </h1>
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="20">Want 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="21">Want 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="22">Want 3</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="23">Want 4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="24">Want 5</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="25">Want 6</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="26">Want 7</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="27">Want 8</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="28">Want 9</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="29">Want 10</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="30">Want 11</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="31">Want 12</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="32">Want 13</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="33">Want 14</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="34">Want 15</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="35">Want 16</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="36">Want 17</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="37">Want 18</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="38">Want 19</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="39">Want 20</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="40">Want 21</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
        <td>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList2" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="41">Want 22</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="42">Want 23</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="43">Want 24</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="44">Want 25</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="45">Want 26</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="46">Want 27</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="47">Want 28</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="48">Want 29</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="49">Want 30</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="50">Want 31</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="51">Want 32</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="52">Want 33</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="53">Want 34</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="54">Want 35</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="55">Want 36</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="56">Want 37</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="57">Want 38</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="58">Want 39</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="59">Want 40</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="60">Want 41</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="61">Want 42</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
        </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="style4">Comment TextBox column 62:</td>
            <td class="style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="62" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
            <td>
              <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList3" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="63">Have 1</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="64">Have 2</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="65">Have 3</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </td>
            <td>
              <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList4" runat="server">
                <asp:ListItem Value="66">Have 4</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="67">Have 5</asp:ListItem>
              </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                         onclick="Button1_Click" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might want to replace the 100 lines of repetitive code with a loop... That would even have been faster to type (if that was any reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things at hand here, almost too much to cover in a single answer, so let me at least preface my comments by suggesting you pick up a basic ASP.NET book and go through some of the basics therein. Looking at your posting, I think you understand a few things, but not broadly enough just yet.

First, the ExecuteInsert method is a problem, and I'm guessing it isn't compiling. You can't name method parameters with a number; that's not a legal identifier. But, beyond that, that huge parameter list is just a problem begging to be fixed....and that brings us to the other notion...getting the data from the page to the back-end code.

Your ASP.NET Control ID declarations cannot be just a numeric ID, because it causes ASP.NET to generate intermediate declarations using that as an identifier that exposes the control to your code-behind. However, numeric identifiers are not legal. I would strongly suggest you rename those ID's to something more descriptive and constructive.

For example, while I'm not sure what its supposed to hold, let's say the asp:TextBox you've declared with ID = "3" is supposed to hold a Last Name. A good ID would, then, be "LastName," which can then be accessed in your codebehind via the identifier LastName, and its contents via the Text property, eg LastName.Text.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="LastName" runat="server" Width="60px"></asp:TextBox>
```

..
from codebehind:
..

```
// access the value of the textbox as (purely an example):
if (LastName.Text=="")
{
    // Do something with a blank last name
};
```

Obviously, you'd need to adapt this to your application, and the same notion to the other inputs.

If you repeat that process for all those ID's, you then realize you have a natural mechanism to access the values provided by a user in the Page_Load event when the Page.IsPostBack value is True. That makes your page *much* easier to read and programmaticallly easier to manage, because you can collect the data from your inputs and supply them to your Insert more cleanly.

The same problem exists with the identifiers in your SQL statement, although using parameters to populate it is actually a good practice.

That's a good start for now. See if what I've suggested gives you a starting point, refine what you've done so far, and see if you can get closer to a workable solution. Good luck.

**EDIT based on discussion with OP**

This should provide a markup and codebehind sample that demonstrates one way to extract the values from a CheckBoxList, a TextBox, and a ListBox from an ASP.NET page and adds those values as SqlParameters to a SqlCommand  for insertion into a fictional sample table.

**

### ASPX Markup for sample page:

**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DemoPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:CheckBoxList id="SampleCheckBox" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="First Value" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Second Value" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Third Value" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="SampleTextBox" Width="50" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ListBox ID="SampleListBox" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem Text="First Value" Value="A"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Second Value" Value="B"></asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="Third Value" Value="C"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:ListBox>
    <asp:Button id="SubmitButton" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="true" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class DemoPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            string strSql = @"Insert Into SampleTable (Check1, Check2, Check3, Text, ListBoxResult) 
                                               Values (@Value1, @Value2, @Value3, @TextValue, @ListResult)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSql);

            // Handle CheckBoxList values
            int checkValue=0;
            foreach (ListItem sampleItem in SampleCheckBox.Items)
            {
                checkValue++; //increment ID used to build parameter name
                string parmName=String.Format("@Value{0}",checkValue);
                SqlParameter newParameter = new SqlParameter();
                newParameter.ParameterName = parmName;
                if (sampleItem.Selected)
                {
                    newParameter.Value = "Y";
                    //column value in DB for field corresponding to sampleItem is "Y"
                }
                else
                {
                    newParameter.Value="N";
                    //column value in DB for field corresponding to sampleItem is "n"
                }
                cmd.Parameters.Add(newParameter);
            }

            // Handle TextBox value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@TextValue", SampleTextBox.Text);

            // Handle ListBox selected value
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ListResult", SampleListBox.SelectedValue);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

**Discussion**

The page hosts one three-item CheckBoxList, one TextBox, and one ListBox. The user may select any one of the items in the CheckBoxList, place any text in the TextBox, and select a value from the LIstBox. The button causes the form to submit, causing the codebehind to execute in a postback mode.

The postback mode causes the SQL data portion to fire in three parts:

1. Regardless of the number of items checked in the CheckBoxList, the values correspond (in this example) to a Y or N value in the sample database. If an item is checked, the value should be "Y", and "N" if it is not. The code iterates through all three ListItems in the CheckBoxList, and adds Parameter objects with names corresponding to the Parameter fields named in the SQL query, setting values of "Y" or "N" as needed. The "parmName" variable is a convenience variable to construct the names of the first three parameters, named Value1, Value2, Value3.
2. The next parameter is taken from the Text property of the SampleTextBox control.
3. The last parameter is taken from the Value property of the selected ListBox ListItem.

With the parameters collected, the ExecuteNonQuery method of the SqlCommand object is fired, executing the statement with the provided values.

Hopefully, this illustrates at least one way of collecting values from an ASP.NET form and writing them to a database. The elements of supplying/buiding the proper connection string, as well as declaring/opening a Connection object, are not illustrated. As the database query is only for demonstration, actual test of this code against a database has not been accomplished, but it does work up to the ExecuteNonQuery() method call.

Comment: I just changed the values to numbers because I did not want my actual values on the site. Thank you for your help. sorry for not stating that I changed the values so that I felt comfortable posting all of my code.

Comment: Ah, okay. I guess then some more detail on the kinds of problems your seeing would be helpful, then, as I'm not sure how to help you.

Comment: I am wondering at this point if having a checkbox list will be an issue posting to the server. the list has an ID but the individual checkboxes do not so how does the server know if the checkbox was checked to upload a Y to that column in the server.

Comment: A CheckBoxList will return a SelectedItem property that you may be able to use to discriminate among the values of concern, at least if you are implementing a single-selection list. You can iterate among the items and inspsect the Selected property if multiple items can be selected. What you may end up needing to do is make some inferences for columns not explicitly returned in any of your lists, eg say you have values X, Y, and Z, and you received a value for "X", so that column will be "Y", thus columns "Y" and "Z" must be "N" (and so forth).

Comment: so what you are saying is use a if then statement. Where if the check box is selected then the value that will be entered is Y and if the check box in the list is empty then return a value of N? Can you give me an example of this based off of the information provided in my post?

Comment: If you are just checking for a single item, CheckBoxList.SelectedItem will give you the selected item directly. If you must check for multiple  values, you'll need to iterate and use something like "if (currentItem.Selected) { // doSomething(); }

Comment: so I will need to do that for each checkbox? is there a way to do it one time for each checkboxlist?

Comment: Well, in theory, you could probably build something to iterate through all the checkboxlists, but I think it would be uglier than just cranking out each one.

Comment: so something like this: `code` CheckBoxList chkbx = (CheckBoxList)FormView1.FindControl("CheckBoxListone"); //Set up connection and command objects //Open connection for (int i = 0; i < chkbx.Items.Count; i++) { if (chkbx.Items[i].Selected) { cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CategoryID", chkbx.Items[i].Value); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); cmd.Parameters.Clear(); } }`code`

Comment: You should be able to reference the control by its ID in the code behind, not have to use FindControl. You still want to collect the data for the other fields before inserting a new record.

Comment: So how would you set it up? Is there a way to call on the pram for all the fields ie:checkbox, text box , drop down?

Comment: @Clay, I'm going to post an extended example of one way to set up a CheckBoxList, a TextBox, and a ListBox and how you might aggregate those values into a sample record in a sample database table. GIve me a few minutes.

Comment: Ok thanks a bunch I feel like I have been getting no where for a week with this, and really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Clay, the new sample I promised is up for your review. Hopefully it illustrates in a chunk of code better than what we could do in comment exchanges :)

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help David! I noticed that you did not set up the Pram = new SQLparameter. Or did you choose to not display this section of the code? Also when collecting the hidden value for the primary key does any code have to be added to the statement above?

Comment: Thanks again for helping and sorry for all the comments lol :)

Comment: The code to set up the new SqlParameter is in there...? "SqlParameter newParameter = new SqlParameter();" roughly in the middle of the codebehind. I made no assumptions about primary keys in the sample INSERT; if the table used an int identity field for its PK, no setup would be necessary in the insert. If the PK consisted of a couple of fields (say LastName and FirstName), they'd just be asp:HiddenField objects and would be accessed in the codebehind like text boxes (and added to the insert acccordingly).

Comment: Sorry I am on a device right now heading out of Chicago and the scroll feature isn't compatable I guess. In my pram[0] I have it set for int so I will just add a field to the table with a int identity field.

Comment: Okay, have a good flight :) Keep in mind you don't have to supply the identity field or a value in an INSERT when  you have an identity field; only need that value on an UPDATE or DELETE. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but not flying out unfortunately, just trying to get to the burbs :( gotta love Chicago traffic! So I just have to add a hidden field to the table and I'm almost good to go, Hotchacha! Im guessing that for radio buttons it's just like the checkboxes. For checkboxes in the select strSQL I should put check(value) correct?

Comment: You can do a RadioButtonList just like the CheckBoxList, with only one coming back selected. If your table already has an integer primary key identity field, you don't need the hidden field for an insert... Glad Ive been able to help - good luck in that traffic!

Comment: So how i listed out all of the param[0] = new sqlparameter("@value", sqlDbType); was not necessary?

Comment: Not  unnecessary, just another way of accomplishing it. Lots of ways to skin these cats :)

Comment: I am getting an error now that says that deals with namespace linq does not exist in the system?!

Comment: Add "using System.Linq" to the top of the source file.

Comment: it is not compatable with asp.net 2.0 :( I was wondring why I was working through so many errors lol

Comment: and what do you mean source file? web.config?!

Comment: add that under the existing system.data? I added data there and it now just moved the error over under data

Comment: It says that eventargs could not be found as well

Comment: Sorry..been out of pocket due to some family issues...I meant to  add "using System.Data.Linq" to the  top of    the .cs file..

Comment: no worries I was able to work through a large amount of the errors which was nice to see, but this Linq does not seem to want to work regardless to data.linq or .linq